# Does official source of data about air routes exists?

Tags: icao, flight-path

I'm interested in the information about air routes of all the world. I need information with following features:

- it must be official (not stolen, without violating any license);
- it should be in digital form;
- it should be in [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System);
- it should cover all of the world;
- it should be free (no payment);
- it shouldn't be detailed (just main routes);
- it shouldn't be actual (current), one or two years outdated is appropriate.

I've realised that some kind of this information is published by [ICAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Civil_Aviation_Organization) at the [AIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Information_Publication), but I can't find it.

So my question is: whether such information is available and where I can find it?

Comment: As you probably know, companies like [Jeppesen](http://www.jeppesen.com) charge a fortune for *current* information of the above sort. Your only hope of finding it for free is the fact that you're willing to accept outdated information. Having said that though, I'm not sure where one would find outdated, accurate info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such information is not available, for free, on a world wide level.

If you are willing to spend some money, you should have a look at [Navigraph](https://www.navigraph.com/), which provides such information on a world wide level, for hobby use.

However, most countries now make their AIP publically available on the internet. Simply search for "[country name] AIP" to look up an AIP for a specific country.

In any AIP, you want to look at part 3 of the ENR section. Usually ENR 3.1, ENR 3.2 or ENR 3.3. Here is an example of from AIP Denmark: [AIP Denmark ENR 3.3 - RNAV routes](http://aim.naviair.dk/AIM%20Documents/AIP%20Danmark/AIP%20PART%202%20-%20EN%20ROUTE%20%28ENR%29/ENR%203%20ATS_RNAV%20ROUTES/EK_ENR_3_3_en.pdf)

This information is digital, official, up to date, free and in WGS84 format. However, you will have to look it up for every country.

If you are looking for a visual overview of airways and RNAV routes in Europe, a good place to start is the [Eurocontrol regional charts](http://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/eurocontrol-regional-charts-erc).

You should also check out [SkyVector](https://skyvector.com/)

Comment: `This information is digital`, when I say about "digital", I mean format which allow automatic processing of that data (without human), something like XML but not PDF or image. Anyway your answer is very useful!

Comment: I'm afraid you won't find anything like that for free, but check out Navigraph as I mentioned in the answer

Comment: `I'm afraid you won't find anything like that for free`, free is wish, but not requirement (I've tried indicate this by using "should" instead of "must").

Answer (score 2):

I a m not sure about the WGS84 convention requirement, but some websites do provide flight data (which might not be up to date), but is fairly new (2012).

Here is a [link](http://arm.64hosts.com/) to one of the websites which provides data about 669 airlines, 3310 air ports covering about 56749 routes. You can also have a look at [this](http://openflights.org/blog/2009/10/13/comprehensive-airline-route-data-released/) and [this](http://openflights.org/data.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately information which you refer does not contain full data (all points) about routes, but only about input and output airports.